# NSURLRequest autorelease?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, memory-management, nsurlconnection

When I use autorelease with NSURLRequest the application crashes.

```
 NSURLRequest *getRequest = [[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:query]] autorelease];
```

I am new to obj-c and I am not sure how the memory management works.  DO I need to manually do a `[getRequest release]` ?

And if so, when should I do it... right after I create the NSURLConnection?

Or does NSURLConnection release the request?

A related question I have is with NSMutableArray.  When I add an object into the array, do I need to do a release of that object after adding it to the array?  What is the memory life cycle of objects added to the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

study this thoroughly before you code in ObjC 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html.

Answers to your questions :

requestWithURL gives an autoreleased object , hence no need to release/autorelease (as a thumb rule, most of the  class (factory) methods provide autoreleased objects - check the documentation before releasing them).

No need to explicitly release objects added to Array/Dictionary. They are released when deleted from Array/List or deleting the collection. (in essence add to array + deleting from array will balance out)

Comment: Thanks.  if I call removeAlObjects on my array, will that also then delete the object(s) added to the array?

Comment: similarly, if I do a objectAtIndex and get a pointer to the object, do I need to release that when I am done with dealing with the object I got?

Comment: @ser605957 objectAtIndex gives you the object stored at that particular index - nothing more and nothing less. Now decide for yourself, if you have to release any thing :)

Comment: I guess not... because its the same object and I have not retained or allocated it again, so the ref count is one

Answer (score 1):

You release an object once you (or the current routine) are finished with it. You do not need to release if you use autorelease (as the name may well imply).

Comment: What about when I put that object into the array... does the array add another reference to it, in which case I need to release after adding it into the array?

Comment: No. Array will release it when the array's deallocated. It has taken ownership and it will relinquish it.

Comment: Ask for it before and after adding it. As far as I understand, `retainCount`s are unreliable.

Comment: Noooooo! :) Don't look at retain count. It might be correct once or twice, you might get away with it if you check it, add the object to an array, then check it again, but it's a bad habit. There's no guarantee that `NSArray`'s internals, or anything else in the frameworks, won't add 100 retains to the object behind your back.

Comment: @Deepak @Josh Caswell I relent. I usually print the retain count to log to make sure it was incremented/decremented as I expected. I do as Deepak suggested, and print before and after the action so that I don't catch autorelease events (usually). But I agree, never build it into the code. I removed the comment in case someone inferred that from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:query]]
```

returns an autoreleased object, so you don't have to add an autorelease message

otherwise you can retain it in a class attribute and release it later